# Ckeditor removes table tags

Tags: ckeditor

I've upgraded the old ckeditor with the new ckeditor, only I'm struggling with the behaviour of the new one.

It seems that the new one removes my complete table.

For example from this input:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            This is a test
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

he will make this:

```
<p>This is a test</p>
```

I need the table, so how can I prevent *ckeditor* to replace my `<table>` tags with a `<p>` tag?

Comment: Do you have an online example? This could be the Advanced Content Filter working, but sounds really weird it being so strict. Documentation for it at http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter - you can test if it's it by setting `allowedContent: true` in your config.

Answer (score 6):

```
config.toolbar = [
    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Table' ] }
];
```

please use the above code as in new versions of ck editor you have to mention tables in toolbar.

Comment: This fix worked for me. Tables were being stripped, adding in the above now preserves them. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When adding table item in config as mentioned in jibran's answer. It gave me an error.

Best thing to do it is to open CKEditor builder given here: https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder

Select table in config and download the editor to use it.